# Set CanExecute to be a method of the data context

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I could be going about this the wrong way. I am trying to put as little code behind in the view as possible, so I want the `CanExecute` and `Executed` events of my command binding to be handled in my viewmodel, which is my data context.

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple, but I can't think how to do it.

The XAML for the command binding:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="DataControls:ParameterCollectionViewModel.UpdateCollection"
                    CanExecute="???"
                    Executed="???"
                    />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

`DataControls:ParameterCollectionViewModel.UpdateCollection` is a static `RoutedCommand`, but the data context is of type `ParameterCollectionViewModel` (not that it matters).

How do I get the event handlers in my data context to be the event handlers in the command binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably be much happier if you used a [`DelegateCommand`](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html) or something similar (an implementation also exists in the Microsoft Prism sources).

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is the method I've gone for.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, you need to add the command to your datacontext. If the datacontext is a DependencyObject, you can simply add a new command to the Commands property.

If the datacontext is not a dependency property, I better hope it's a view model. In that case, you can use RelayCommand or DelegateCommand (actually, they are both the same).

I am one of the developers of [Catel](http://catel.codeplex.com), an open-source MVVM framework, which also supports commands. You can find more information about [Catel commands](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CatelPart3.aspx#DefiningCommands).